# In a sequence of $n$ integers, must there be a contiguous subsequence that sums to a multiple of $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be integers.  Then are there indices $1\le a\le b\le n$ such that $$\sum_{i=a}^b x_i$$ is a multiple of $n$?

Comment: I originally ruled out the possibility that $a=b$, but this is necessary: The sequence $1,0,1$ has no subsequence that sums to a multiple of 3 unless you allow $a=b=2$.

Comment: A sequence of $n$ elements is necessary for there to be a subsequence that sums to a multiple of $n$.  The sequence $1,1,\ldots, 1$ of length $n-1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: This is a zero-sum problem, similar to the [EGZ](http://planetmath.org/ErdHosGinzburgZivTheorem) theorem.  Your version adds the condition that the subsequence be consecutive, while EGZ adds the condition of exactly n summands in the subsequence.

Comment: This is also discussed at http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pigeonhole/group.shtml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $$s_k = \sum_{i=1}^k x_i\pmod n.$$  If  $s_k$ is zero for any $k$, we have found the desired subsequence ($a=1, b=k$), so suppose all the $s_k$ are nonzero.  There are $n$ of them, each in the range $1,\ldots,n-1$, so two, say $s_{a}$ and $s_b$, must be equal.  Then since $s_b - s_a = 0$, we have $$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^b x_i - \sum_{i=1}^{a} x_i & = 0\pmod n \\
\sum_{i=a+1}^b x_i & = 0\pmod n
\end{align}$$

as desired.

(Note that if $a+1 = b$, that is all right; it just means that $x_b$ itself is a multiple of $n$.)