# In a set of $n$ integers where no proper nonempty subset sums to a multiple of $n$, all elements are congruent

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

I want to prove the following:

> Let $A$ be a set of $n$ positive integers such that for any subset $M$, $M$ neither empty nor equal to $A$, the sum of elements of $M$ is not divisible by $n$. Prove that the elements of $A$ are all congruent $\pmod n.$

The $n=2$ case is obvious (both numbers must be odd). For $n=3$, the only possible residues are 1,2, and it is obvious that if both residues are present then their sum is divisible by 3, contradiction. 
$n=4$ is again easily provable by casework (since you can't have both 1 and 3 as residues in the same set.)

However, i do not know how one would generalize this. For starters, if $r$ is a residue $\pmod n$, you cannot include both $r$ and $n-r$ as residues in the same set, thus obtaining that such a set has at most $\left \lfloor \dfrac{n+1}{2} \right \rfloor$ distinct residues.( $\lfloor a\rfloor$ is the integer part of $a$)

How can I finish the proof?

Comment: Would it be possible to try to use (strong)-induction on $n$ ? Just wondering...

Comment: In the future, when you make a title, describe your question specifically instead of "trouble with X", "question about X", etc. (More people in the future will find your question and benefit from it!) Great question, by the way.

Comment: Several closely related questions: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933631/prove-that-there-are-i-and-j-with-1-le-i-le-j-le-n-such-that-a-ia?rq=1), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421592/in-a-sequence-of-n-integers-must-there-be-a-contiguous-subsequence-that-sums?rq=1), [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118148/prove-that-any-set-of-2015-numbers-has-a-subset-whos-sum-is-divisible-by-2015?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List out the $n$ elements of $A$ as $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$. We will show that either a proper, nonempty subset of them sums to $0$ mod $n$, or else they are all congruent. Consider the partial sums $s_i = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_i$, for $0 \le i \le n$.

By the pigeonhole principle, two of these $n+1$ partial sums fall into the same residue class mod $n$, say $s_i = s_j$. Unless $i = 0$ and $j = n$, we are done because we get $a_{i+1} + a_{i+2} + \cdots + a_{j} \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$. Therefore, assume that $s_0 \equiv s_n \equiv 0$ but that the $n-1$ other partial sums are exactly the $n-1$ nonzero residues mod $n$.

Now for any $1 \le i \le n-1$, consider switching $a_{i}$ and $a_{i+1}$,
forming new partial sums $s_0, s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_{i}', s_{i+1}', \ldots, s_n$.
If this causes two of the new partial sums to coincide mod $n$, we are again done as before. So we may assume that the collection of partial sums of the new sequence are still all distinct, specifically: $\{s_i', s_{i+1}'\} \equiv \{s_i, s_{i+1}\}$.
Subtracting $s_{i-1}$, $\{s_i' - s_{i-1}, s_{i+1}' - s_{i-1}\} \equiv \{s_i - s_{i-1}, s_{i+1} - s_{i-1}\}$. That is,
$$
\{a_{i+1}, a_{i+1} + a_i\} \equiv \{a_i, a_i + a_{i+1}\}.
$$
In general, if $\{q,r\} = \{s,t\}$, either $q = s$ and $r = t$ or $q = t$ and $r = s$.
In this case, either $a_{i+1} \equiv a_i + a_{i+1}$ or $a_{i+1} \equiv a_i$.
If $a_{i+1} \equiv a_i + a_{i+1}$, then $a_{i} \equiv 0$, thus $\{a_{i}\}$ is a one-element set that sums to $0$ mod $n$.
Otherwise, $a_i \equiv a_{i+1} \pmod{n}$.

Applying this for all $i$, we get that $a_1 \equiv a_2 \equiv \cdots \equiv a_n$. (We may further notice that this common residue must be relatively prime to $n$.) $\square$